# Are there accumulation points of $\bar{A}$ that are not accumulation points of $A$?

Tags: general-topology

Some definitions:

If $x\in X$, then a neighbourhood of $x \in X$ is a subset of $X$ that contains an open set containing $x$. It $A\subseteq X$, then an accumulation point of $A$ is an $x\in X$ with the property that every neighbourhood of $x$ in $X$ contains some point of $A$ other than $x$. The set of all accumulation points of $A$ in $X$ is denoted $A'$ and called the derived set of $A$. The closure of $A$ in $X$ denote $\bar{A} = A \cup A'$.

Here is my attempt thus far:

Suppose $x$ is an accumulation point of $\bar{A}$ that is not an accumulation point of $A$. As $x$ is not an accumulation point of $A$, we can find some neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $(U-\{x\}) \cap A = \varnothing$. However, as $x$ is an accumulation point of $\bar{A}$, $U$ must contain some point $y$ of $\bar{A}$ other than $x$. Clearly, $y\in \bar{A} - A \subseteq A'$ is an accumulation point of $A$. This implies $U$ contains some point of $A$ other than $y$, so either $x\in A$, or $U$ contains some point of $A$ other than $x$.

It seems to me that there is the possibility of an isolated point of $A$ becoming an accumulation point after taking closure, but I have been unable to come up with an example where this is true, although I seem to be unable to prove that such a situation is impossible.

Comment: How do you define $\overline A$? Is it the set of all accumulation points of $A$? (note that there are several equivalent characterizations of $\overline A$, so it's important to know which of them you take as the definition)

Comment: Hi I've added the definitions I'm working with to the question

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you are wooking in a Huasdorff space. $U$ must contain infinitely many points of $\overline A$: If it has only finitely many then  we can find another neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $V$ contains no point of $\overline A$ other than $x$ which is  a contradiction to the fact that $x$ is an accumulation point of $\overline A$.

Thus there is a point $y$ of $\overline A$ in $U\setminus x$. Can you finish the argument now?

Counter-example in the general case: Consider the real line with the indiscrete topology. Let $A=\{0\}$. Then $\overline A=\mathbb R$. $0$ is an accumualtion point of $\overline A$ but it is not an accumulation point of $A$.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to show the result or disprove it for general topological spaces?

Comment: @pofucurj I have added a counter-example for the general case.

Comment: Ah of course, in hindsight that's kind of obvious! Thanks

Comment: This proof in the Hausdorff case also holds in the T1 case.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, that is true. Thanks for the comment.